# Upper bound for $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^{r}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How one can prove that $\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^{r} \leqslant \dfrac{k + r + 1}{k+1}$ for $-1 \leqslant r \leqslant 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried to construct a function $f(x) = 1 + \dfrac{r}{x+1} -\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{r}$ and compute its derivative $f'_{x}(x)$, and it turned out that this function is monotonically decreasing over $x \in [e - 1, +\infty)$. Thus, in this interval $f(x) \leqslant f(e-1)$. But it is not what I needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow I feel the upper bound in the title should be something like $\exp(r/k)$.  But this is not the question and anyway does not seem to be true for $-1 \lt r \lt 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^r \leq 1-\frac{r}{k+1}
\end{align}
since $0\leq r \leq 1$. However, observe
\begin{align}
1-\frac{1}{k+1}= \frac{k}{k+1} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^r= \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{-r}= \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-r}.
\end{align}

As an exercise, you could prove the above Bernoulli inequality using derivative comparison.